# Securing a google app engine application with oauth2 on call from a Wildfly/Keycloak secured web application behind a firewall

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, wildfly, keycloak

### Requirements

- My requirements are to write a secure web application that runs behind a firewall and via the OAuth2 protocol accesses a google app engine application.  The google app engine should not be able to be accessed in any other way (save by the developer/admin). The programming language is Java. The authorization is to be server to server.

### Deployment

- I will have a "gate keeper" application running on **WildFly (JBoss) with Keycloak** and will use active directory to login my users on this **web application running behind the firewall**.  In this way, everyone who has an account at the business I am servicing should have access to the google app engine application.  Again, this processing runs behind the business's firewall as a Java EE web application deployed to WildFly.
- The next step after a successful login is for the user to get redirected to the web page that the google app engine is servicing.  **I don't want any other users (except my developer account/owner account) to be able to reach this url.**
- I have created the JSON user credential file and downloaded from the google developers console for my google app engine project. 
  I also have included the google-api-client in my maven pom file on my gatekeeper project.

  `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.20.0</version>
  </dependency>`
  from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup

### Questions

- *How do I code (Java) the wonderful world of OAuth 2.0 using the google api client?* I imagine that I will have code on the "gate keeper web application" (Java) and probably some configuration xml in my **appengine-web.xml.**  Will my app engine application need any additional code? Does anyone have step by step instructions or a sample code/configuration? I have read https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount and yet am at a loss on how to apply.

Thanks in advance for your help.  I would guess that this is a very common scenario for SaaS providers?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular this question is too broad. show what you tried and a specific issue.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome to this fine site.  My question is not really that broad.  I am looking for an example, a quick-start something of that sort to focus my implementation.  I figure the call to the google api client will have a certain format, the appengine-web.xml another.  I have not found this in the literature.  I imagine others have solved this problem.  I am looking for that expertise.  1.  How to call service to service with the google client api.  2. what the appengine-web.xml looks like.  3. any other expertise the people of this fine site can provide.  Thank you.

Comment: put that specific info in your question not here. still too broad as many tutorials and documentation cover this. follow one and show specific issues.

Comment: Just checking my understanding: you have an internal Keycloak server and an external Google Apps Engine. You want to protect your Google Apps Engine application by authenticating the users via your Keycloak server. Is this about right?

Comment: Your understanding is correct!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned previously, you're asking at least 2 questions. First, how to authenticate an application against a OpenID Connect 1.0 authentication server - in this case, Keycloak - behind a firewall. Secondly, how to use the `google-api-client`.

I'd suggest taking a look at the [OAuth Bible](http://oauthbible.com/) to understand how OAuth 2.0 Two Legged and Three Legged flows are implemented. Three Legged authentication is more secure but your firewall will pose a problem.

Also, you'll be more likely to get help if you break out the `google-api-client` part into a more concretely defined question.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The google api client was the easy part.  Getting KeyCloak configured was more interesting.  I had to whitelist behind the firewall which makes perfect sense.